# How do I extract JSON Property Value based on Key in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps I have an "HTTP Receive" which receives the information below.
How do I extract the value from key Location in the Properties?

Note I have >100 Properties

```
{
   "Firstname":"Alice",
   "Lastname":"Smith",
   "Properties":[
      {
         "Key":"Age",
         "Value":"39"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Location",
         "Value":"London"
      },
      {
         "Key":"Id",
         "Value":"93405435"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Not enough information to assist.  What is the end goal of this Logic App?

Comment: I want to extract the Location from the Properties since it needs to be send to API Management, so I'm looking for a way to temporarily store the information in a variable and send it using a HTTP POST Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the process design of the following `Azure logic app`：

[image]

Then you can get the value based on the filtered result.

[image]